# setup resque with mongoid

Tags: mongoid, ruby-on-rails-5, resque, ruby-2.3

I have got my resque setup process complete, tested successfully with a simple job. It is recommended to close ActiveRecord connection in the pool setup rake task and establish the connection on `after_prefork` to avoid stale connections before forking.

I now need to do this for mongoid, I can establish the connection by doing `Mongoid.load! 'path_to_mongoid.yml'` but I can't seem to find  a way to close the connection, I tried `disconnect, close` methods but I don't know if they get reconnected or if it doesn't kill off the connection. I tried this in a rails console, I was able to test it with ActiveRecord doesn't work with mongoid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like `disconnect` does actually kills off the mongoid connection, I was getting confused because I was expecting an similar error I got when I tried out with active record but looks like mongoid autoconnects when needed.

I verified that the connection was killed using mongo console, you can do a `db.serverStatus().connections` to view the number of connections and see that disconnect will decrease the current connections.